# ASP.NET MVC - Routing Structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, routes

I have an ASP.NET MVC 4.5 app. In this app, I have two controllers: `Parent` and `Children`. The look something like this:

```
[RoutePrefix("dashboard/parents")]
public partial class ParentsController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [Route("add")]
  public ActionResult Add()
  {
    return View();
  }
}

[RoutePrefix("dashboard/children")]
public partial class ChildrenController : Controller
{
  public ActionResult Index()
  {
    return View();
  }

  [Route("add")]
  public ActionResult Add()
  {
    return View();
  }
}
```

At this time, these controllers work how I want. However, in my `ChildrenController`, I want to add something like an overload to the add route. In other words, I'd like for the user to be able to visit: /dashboard/parents/{parentId}/children/add. This URL would be used to add a child to a specific parent. My question is, how do I update my controllers to allow for this type of scenario?

thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you are looking for the is "~" to override your default routeprefix.. The following example is taken from the [asp.net](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/attribute-routing-in-web-api-2#prefixes) website which tells you how to accomplish the task.

```
[RoutePrefix("api/books")]
public class BooksController : ApiController
{
    // GET /api/authors/1/books
    [Route("~/api/authors/{authorId:int}/books")]
    public IEnumerable<Book> GetByAuthor(int authorId) { ... }

    // ...
}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know about the tilde approach. Thanks for sharing.